# WGCNA installation issue in R

Tags: r, installation, package

When I try

```
install.packages('WGCNA')
```

I get the following in particular "Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘WGCNA’ had non-zero exit status".

```
Installing package into ‘/gpfs/HOME/iputilin/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/WGCNA_1.71.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1170723 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB

* installing *source* package ‘WGCNA’ ...
** package ‘WGCNA’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG -DWITH_THREADS -I"/gpfs/HOME/iputilin/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c corFunctions-utils.c -o corFunctions-utils.o
corFunctions-utils.c: In function ‘threadSlowCalcCor’:
corFunctions-utils.c:891:14: warning: unused variable ‘vy’ [-Wunused-variable]
  891 |   double vx, vy;
      |              ^~
corFunctions-utils.c:891:10: warning: unused variable ‘vx’ [-Wunused-variable]
  891 |   double vx, vy;
      |          ^~
corFunctions-utils.c:890:16: warning: unused variable ‘yy’ [-Wunused-variable]
  890 |   double *xx, *yy;
      |                ^~
corFunctions-utils.c:890:11: warning: unused variable ‘xx’ [-Wunused-variable]
  890 |   double *xx, *yy;
      |           ^~
corFunctions-utils.c: In function ‘threadSlowCalcCor2’:
corFunctions-utils.c:1197:18: warning: unused variable ‘yy’ [-Wunused-variable]
 1197 |   double * xx, * yy;
      |                  ^~
corFunctions-utils.c:1197:12: warning: unused variable ‘xx’ [-Wunused-variable]
 1197 |   double * xx, * yy;
      |            ^~
corFunctions-utils.c: In function ‘threadSlowCalcCor2_weighted’:
corFunctions-utils.c:1376:18: warning: unused variable ‘vy’ [-Wunused-variable]
 1376 |   double vx = 0, vy = 0;
      |                  ^~
corFunctions-utils.c:1376:10: warning: unused variable ‘vx’ [-Wunused-variable]
 1376 |   double vx = 0, vy = 0;
      |          ^~
corFunctions-utils.c:1375:18: warning: unused variable ‘yy’ [-Wunused-variable]
 1375 |   double * xx, * yy;
      |                  ^~
corFunctions-utils.c:1375:12: warning: unused variable ‘xx’ [-Wunused-variable]
 1375 |   double * xx, * yy;
      |            ^~
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG -DWITH_THREADS -I"/gpfs/HOME/iputilin/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c corFunctions.c -o corFunctions.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG -DWITH_THREADS -I"/gpfs/HOME/iputilin/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c myMatrixMultiplication.c -o myMatrixMultiplication.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG -DWITH_THREADS -I"/gpfs/HOME/iputilin/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic  -c networkFunctions.c -o networkFunctions.o
networkFunctions.c: In function ‘tomSimilarityFromAdj’:
networkFunctions.c:260:31: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘FCONE’
  260 |            & beta, tom, nGenes FCONE FCONE);
      |                               ^~~~~~
      |                               )
networkFunctions.c: In function ‘tomSimilarityFromAdj_call’:
networkFunctions.c:604:23: warning: unused variable ‘maxPOutliers’ [-Wunused-variable]
  604 |   double *adj, *tom, *maxPOutliers;
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [networkFunctions.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘WGCNA’
* removing ‘/gpfs/HOME/iputilin/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/WGCNA’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/gpfs/tmp/tmp_genom/RtmpoqXx8J/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("WGCNA") :
  installation of package ‘WGCNA’ had non-zero exit status
```

Do you have any idea why is it so and how to fix it?
I don't really understand the problem, because I'm new in WCGNCA alaysis and its application in R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will need BiocManager:

```
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
       install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(version = "3.16")
# As of November 2, 2022 that's the latest version, so you might need to update 
# the version number, since they change about every 6 months
```

Then you need to install packages that are not on CRAN:

```
BiocManager::install(c("GO.db", "preprocessCore", "impute") )
```

And make sure that you have all the CRAN-hosted dependencies from the package DESCRIPTION file listed below (which includes pkg:Rcpp that you are possibly missing or need a newer version):

```
Depends: R (>= 3.0), dynamicTreeCut (>= 1.62), fastcluster
Imports: stats, grDevices, utils, matrixStats (>= 0.8.1), Hmisc, splines, 
     foreach, doParallel, survival, parallel, AnnotationDbi, Rcpp (>= 0.11.0)
```

Now you are probably ready to install WGCNA.

```
install.packages("WGCNA")
```

(I got success with this shortened version, but BiocManager will want to update all the packages it knows about and for me, this month anyway, that was 400+ packages long and I was getting ready to go to bed, so I'm now letting that long process run so I will have a "fresh" version of the Bioc packages in my library.)